# 36v, 4.5A battery charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

So, I'm a High school student, and for engineering, our project requires chargine a semi-large array of UPS batteries. The batteries need to output 36v and 4.5A max, and I plan on getting a transformer capable of putting out enough power to charge them.

What my issue is, is finding a way to disconnect the battery bank from the transformer when they are charged.

I have asked my father, who has forgotten more than I know, and he's said that there were likely IC's out there to do what I need. I found [this IC](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/103138/MICROCHIP/MCP73828.html), which is kinda similar to what I need to do, but this thing can't handle anywhere near the wattage I need.

Is there an IC to do what I need, or will I need to design my own? If I have to design my own, how would I go about doing it. What components would I need to use, and what are their functions. I want to understand why they're doing what they do.

TL;DR: Need a 36v 4.5A lead acid smart charger, and want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Linear has some ICs that COULD fit your needs. But I haven't looked through the datasheet, so you'll have to check.

ICs I found are the LTC4000 and LTC4020 and at a first glance they look like they can handle high voltages and currents. LTC4000 has an external step-down converter, while LTC4020 uses four mosfets.

Here is the table I filtered on the Linear website. Curiously there are also LED drivers.. :?

http://www.linear.com/parametric/Battery_Charger_IC#!cols_1806,1112,1067,1068,1367,1069,1033,1032!s_1067,0!gtd_!1033_>=36!1067_>=8!1806_Lead Acid